# How to save jpeg data that is identical to the original jpeg file using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, jpeg

I'm using OpenCV and Python. I have loaded a jpeg image into a numpy array. Now i want to save it back into jpeg format, but since the image was not modified, I don't want to compress it again. Is it possible to create a jpeg from the numpy array that is identical with the jpeg that it was loaded from?

I know this workflow (decode-encode without doing anything) sounds a bit stupid, but keeping the original jpeg data is not an option. I'm interested if it is possible to recreate the original jpeg just using the data at hand.

The question is different from [Reading a .JPG Image and Saving it without file size change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323085), as I don't modify anything in the picture. I really want to restore the original jpeg file based on the data at hand. I assume one could bypass the compression steps (the compression artifacts are already in the data) and just write the file in jpeg format. The question is, if this is possible with OpenCV.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a .JPG Image and Saving it without file size change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323085/reading-a-jpg-image-and-saving-it-without-file-size-change)

Comment: No it is not. I added a paragraph, explaining why.

Comment: Yeah well, i think it is.. wether you change one value or not is not relevant. And the Answers to the other Question contain exactly the info you need: For Example: "There’s no general way to know what the original quality setting was."  which means encoding and recoding changes the file.

Comment: I don't think so. One example. If I have *unmodified* jpeg data, I could just write the data back to jpeg without the actual compression steps. More specifically without the down sampling part (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Encoding), because the image is already downsampled correctly, which you can see by having a close look at one of the color channels of the image. If I modify any pixel in the image, the image would have to be downsampled again in order for the jpeg constraints to hold.

Comment: if you have *unmodified jpeg data* can't you just bypass opencv altogether and write the raw bytes out to a file?

Comment: @SiHa because I want the resulting file to be *identical* with the original jpeg. If I'd just save the raw data I had a bitmap-style image format. Before jpegs are saved to disk some more (non destructive) steps are performed on the data, e.g. the zig-zag ordering of the pixels.

Comment: Ah. So not quite the unmodified data then.

Comment: Well, I didn't modify the data in a sense that no pixel was changed. But the data was loaded using `cv2.imdecode` which converts the data from jpeg format into a BGR-bitmap format. The question is how to undo this operation without compressing (i.e. down sampling) the already compressed data again.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `params` of `imwrite`? According to OpenCV doc: For JPEG, it can be a quality ( CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY ) from 0 to 100 (the higher is the better). Default value is 95. Setting it to 100 should do the trick

Comment: Even with 100 jpeg is still a lossy format, no way around that. If you want to save exactly what you loaded try a lossles format like png or bmp.

Comment: There is just no way to can be 100% sure to recreate the exact same JPEG file as was originally read, if all you have is decoded pixels (how can you even know it was JPEG?). *"keeping the original jpeg data is not an option"* WHY? This really is the *only* way.

Answer (score 1):

Clarified answer, following comment below:

What you say makes no sense at all; You say that you have the raw, unmodified, RGB data. No you don't. You have the **uncompressed** data that has been **reconstructed** from the **compressed** jpeg file.

The JPEG standards specify how to un-compress an image / video. There is nothing in the standard about how to actually do this compression, so your original image data could have been compressed any one of a zillion different ways. You have no way of knowing the decoding steps that were required to recreate your data, so you cannot reverse them.

Image this.

> "I have a number, 44, please tell me how I can get the original
>   numbers that this came from"

This is, essentially, what you are asking.

The only way you can do what you want (other than just copy the original file) is to read the image into an array *before* loading into openCV. Then if you want to save it, then just write the raw array to a file, something like this:

```
fi = 'C:\\Path\\to\\Image.jpg'
fo = 'C:\\Path\\to\\Copy_Image.jpg'
with open(fi,'rb') as myfile:
    im_array = np.array(myfile.read())

# Do stuff here

image = cv2.imdecode(im_array)

# Do more stuff here

with open(fo,'wb') as myfile:
    myfile.write(im_array)
```

Of course, it means you will have the data stored twice, effectively, in memory, but this seems to me to be your only option.

Sometimes, no matter how hard you want to do something, you have to accept that it just cannot be done.

Comment: As I said in my original post: storing the original jpeg data is *not* an option. The task here is to reproduce the identical jpeg given the RGB data of a jpeg image.